# AsyncTask + JSON parsing to Listview only sometimes shows data

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

Sometimes it shows data, sometimes it shows nothing.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfNews = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ReadJSON().execute("url");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String st = readURL(url[0]);
            Log.d("st", st);
            return st;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d(i+":jsonArray object", jsonArray.toString() + " size= " + jsonArray.length());
                    JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject img = productObject.getJSONObject("image");
                    JSONObject da = img.getJSONObject("data");

                    arraylist1.add(new HotNews(
                            da.getString("filename"),
                            productObject.getString("title"),
                            productObject.getString("article_by"),
                            productObject.getString("date_publish"),
                            productObject.getString("short_description")
                    ));
                }

                Log.d("jsonArray news list1", arraylist1.size() + "");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.list_view_adapter, arraylist1);
            listOfNews.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

    private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            //create url object
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            //create url connection
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            //wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();

    }

}
```

---

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HotNews> {

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<HotNews> arrayList) {
        super(context, resource,arrayList);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_adapter, parent, false);
        }
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagetitle);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            doer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doer);
            date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
            text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

            final HotNews news = getItem(position);

            Picasso.with(getContext()).load("url" + news.getImage()).noFade().into(image);
            title.setText(news.getTitle());
            doer.setText(news.getDoer());
            date.setText(news.getDate());
            text.setText(news.getContent());
            return v;
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't execute an AsyncTask on the UI Thread. The whole point of the AsyncTask is to get off of the UI Thread...

Comment: can you give me an example or correct my code cos,i really not understand

Comment: Just don't use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`.  I don't know where you saw an example of that, but it's wrong

Comment: And check your website's data. If nothing is returning or it isn't formatted correctly, then, yes, you'll see nothing

Comment: after i remove it now it displays data but it lost some data

Comment: I limited 10 data to show but it displays only 7 data

Comment: Limited how? `jsonArray.length()`?

Comment: by url www.dfjdfjdfjf/limit=10..in API

Comment: Without knowing the actual URL, I don't know how you expect us to help you

Comment: http://www.dap-news.com/kh/api/article/latest?10

Comment: And does `Log.d("jsonArray news list1", arraylist1.size() + "");` print out 10, or not?

Comment: sometime 10 sometime 7

Comment: do you have other way to do it?

Comment: Nope. That website is returning either 7 or 10 of the latest articles. If you always expect 10, then contact the administrator of the website

Comment: but sometime 3 ,4,5,7...

Comment: I don't know what to tell you... You asked the API for a *limit* of 10, not exactly 10.

Comment: when i change such as you said...it works but now the same to before..it means that still not see anything sometimes

Comment: They said it displays 10..

Comment: it's ok..no problem..i'll try more to search.

Comment: I guess if you ever hit `catch (JSONException e)`, then that would prevent an item from being added to the list.

Comment: i don't know.i'm asking you and other.

Comment: can you help me to check  JSONObject img = productObject.getJSONObject("image"); because when i remove this image it can show all data but when i use this to get image. i have problem sometime has all data ,sometime no data.

Comment: You never use the img variable, though

Comment: Try putting the try-catch inside the for-loop. Currently, if you ever get a JSON exception, then the whole loop will end, and you get partial data

Comment: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for image

Comment: I probably should have asked for the logcat sooner. That makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
public class HomeFragment  extends Fragment {

private View view;
private ArrayList<HotNews> arraylist1;
private ListView listOfNews;

private int SUCCESS = 1;
private int FAILS = 0;
private int NO_DATA = 2;
private int ERROR = -1;
private ListViewAdapter adapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfNews = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter();
    listOfNews.setAdapter(adapter);

    new ReadJSON().execute("url");


    return view;
}

public class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... url) {
        String response = readURL(url[0]);
        Log.d("response ", response);


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            arraylist1.clear();

            if(jsonArray.length()>0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d(i + ":jsonArray object", jsonArray.toString() + " size= " + jsonArray.length());
                    JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject img = productObject.getJSONObject("image");
                    JSONObject da = img.getJSONObject("data");

                    arraylist1.add(new HotNews(
                            da.getString("filename"),
                            productObject.getString("title"),
                            productObject.getString("article_by"),
                            productObject.getString("date_publish"),
                            productObject.getString("short_description")
                    ));
                }
            }else{
                return NO_DATA;
            }
            Log.d("jsonArray news list1", arraylist1.size() + "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        Log.d("parseResponse", integer + "");
        if(integer==SUCCESS){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else if(integer==ERROR){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Server or Exception Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(integer==NO_DATA){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Some thing went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist1.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ListViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_adapter, parent, false);
            holder = new ListViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ListViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }


        final HotNews news = arraylist1.get(position);


        holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
        holder.doer.setText(news.getDoer());
        holder.date.setText(news.getDate());
        holder.text.setText(news.getContent());

        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("url" + news.getImage()).noFade().into(holder.image);
        return v;
    }

    class ListViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView title,doer,date,text;
        public ListViewHolder(View v){
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagetitle);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            doer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doer);
            date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
            text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

}


private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        //create url object
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        //create url connection
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        //wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();

}

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answers more than "try this"? What did you change / fix?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error, which is crashing the entire loop. You may be requesting 10 objects, but at the first object without that `image` attribute, it is exiting.

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for image

So, recommendation (other than using Retrofit to manage your JSON API's) would be to use the `optType()` methods rather than the `getType()` methods of the JSON objects.

For example,

```
JSONObject img = productObject.optJSONObject("image");
```

This will set `img` to `null` when the `"image"` attribute does not exist.

Just be aware of that later in case you have a NullPointerException when trying to use `img` on this line

```
JSONObject da = img.getJSONObject("data");
```

Comment: thank you .it works when i test condition if (object!=null) but it has 6 data.some pages 1 data ..now it works all

Comment: i mean that now it always show data but the number of data always 6 or 8 data not 10  before sometime it doesn't show data

Comment: Yes... Because 4 or 2 of your data do not have an image. I don't know what more you expect... You cannot fix that

Comment: ohh it maybe like this